# = sign in gmail message body

Tags: php, encoding, gmail

I'm retrieving the messages of my Gmail account, and I'm finding '=' signs in the body, with some hex codes.

This is an example:

> Na
>   pagina**=**  para anunciar poderia ter as
>   op**=C3=A7=C3=B5**es de Estados , Cidades
>   e Bair**=** ros .
>  
>  Ex :
>   S**=C3=A3**o paulo 
>  Diadema , Sant**=**

I have highlighted in bold these parts. Of course, in Gmail these codes are not visible.

What should I do?

Comment: This question sounds like [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're in [quoted-printable encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

You can use PHP's built-in [`quoted_printable_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) function to decode it.

Comment: There's also the imap_qprint function, that I think does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

These look like escape codes, the type that, if they were in a URL, would normally be %C3%A7%C3%B5.  This has them in decimal.  Are the characters showing up at all, as in, do they take up any space in the string?  I think they are special characters with diacriticals...

S=C3=A3o paulo, in particular, seems to agree with this assessment.